# How to hide page when no records found oracle report

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oraclereports

I have report with 2 pages. In one page information about patient with calculated charges and fees. On 2nd page information about complaint details from patient. I want on 2nd page when no records found then only show 1 page on browser as PDF Document.

I am using oracle report builder 11G.

How to achieve this target?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Reports objects have **format triggers**. They return Boolean value.

In 2nd page's query create a summary column which will return count of rows returned (let's call it `CS_COUNT`). Refer to it in 2nd page's **frame** format trigger, e.g.

```
return :cs_count > 0;
```

which means:

- if there are rows returned, `CS_COUNT` will be larger than 0, so - return `TRUE` and display that frame
- otherwise, `FALSE` will be returned and nothing will be displayed

Comment: I added summary column under Q_2. added format trigger but getting error  
 
REP-1306: Summary column CS_COUNT has an invalid source.

Comment: I think OP don't want to have a hidden page, but no page should be generated when condition is met ( generated only one PDF page ).

Comment: If Reports say that it has an invalid source, what is it set to? Should be e.g. an ID column from Q_2 or similar.

Comment: In Q_2 I have ID column. Add summary column CS_COUNT and set to function=count, source=ID_column. Trailer Section > Body > Format Trigger. Now getting error

REP-1314: Format trigger M_G_MOFID1_GRPFR references column CS_COUNT at the wrong frequency.